# How can I get the icon from Virtmgmt.msc?

Tags: windows

There was a msc file on my computer, the full path is `C:\WINDOWS\System32\virtmgmt.msc`.
I know it was a xml file factly, and I open it and found the icon tag line as follow.

```xml
<Icon Index="0" File="VMHost.ico">
```

But I could not found the `VMHost.ico` file either in `C:\WINDOWS\System32` or any other directories. I even use the tool `Everything` to search the file in all my disks, and there was no matched items.

As a contrast, there was a `C:\WINDOWS\system32\compmgmt.msc` file on my computer, and the icon tag line has the full path of the icon file.

```xml
<Icon Index="2" File="%windir%\system32\mycomput.dll">
```

The `%windir%` means `c:\windows` on my computer, so the full path is `c:\windows\system32\mycomput.dll` and the file exists. Then I invoke win32 api `ExtractAssociatedIcon` with that full path and index and successfully retrieve the `HICON`.

I found another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711354/extract-icons-from-a-msc-file), but is does not solve the problem. So how can I get the icon file `VMHost.ico`?

I search the `VMHost.ico` file in all my disks, and there was no matched items.

Comment: What is "Virtmgmt.msc"?

Comment: Use the standard API for getting icons for files: SHGetFileInfo(SHGFI_ICON).

Comment: The function `SHGetFileInfo` has the same effect as `ExtractAssociatedIcon`. When I invoke them with the msc file path, they all retrieve a blank file icon ![](http://39.105.27.161:50080/static/img/6hi6etKfv0sNSGnTkj9Tbo_32_32.png), not the fact icon ![](http://39.105.27.161:50080/static/img/4ijfiyKEacFEfBe3SeRvqP_113_128.png).